# DOJO Build how to create a layer?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojo-build

I have the following profile for a DOJO custom build (boilerplate from https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate).

I need to create a layer for my custom code with result as a `single .js` file for my custom code.

At the moment the code take all files for `custom`, and process theme (minification) but the output it is always not concatenated.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
var profile = {

    basePath: '../src/',
    action: 'release',
    cssOptimize: 'comments',
    mini: true,
    optimize: 'closure',
    layerOptimize: 'closure',
    packages: [
        'dgrid',
        'dijit',
        'dojo',
        'dojox',
        'put-selector',
        'xstyle',
        'custom'
    ],
    stripConsole: 'all',
    selectorEngine: 'lite',
    layers: {
        'custom/': {
            include: ["custom/bootstrap"]
        },
    },
    staticHasFeatures: {
        'dojo-trace-api': false,
        'dojo-log-api': false,
        'dojo-publish-privates': false,
        'dojo-sync-loader': false,
        'dojo-xhr-factory': false,
        'dojo-test-sniff': false
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the layer name should not have a / at the end.

Did you try

```
'custom': {
```

???